# The effect of the mixed signals probability distribution on the ICA performance

Tags: source-separation, ica, independence

Does the mixed signals distribution affect the [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) performance? I mean the ability of ICA to get the sources.

- Assume that the mixed signals follows a Gaussian distribution and of course the sources do not follow Gaussian distributions. Then, this implies that we have large independent components or sources, so will the ICA be able to get all of that components?
- On the other hand, if the mixed signals follows a Poisson distribution, should that mean something regarding the ICA method? I mean should we expect that the ICA will not be able to extract the sources of that signals in an efficient way?

Comment: "Does the mixed signals distribution affect on the ICA performance?" yes, but I guess you've been expecting that...

Comment: Other than that, those are four "?" in one question... I've got the impression you've not read too much about the class of methods ICA is so far, and my gut feeling is that you'd much rather like a good textbook recommendation than you're expecting us to answer your very open-ended questions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller then would you recommend a good textbook ?(I've just added the 5th question mark)

Comment: Sounds like a job for Karhunen / Hyvärinen's "independent component analysis", Wiley. Good thing: you can read the [intro chapter](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/book/intro.pdf) online and figure out whether it's good for you). Maybe Pierre's 1994 [paper](http://mlsp.cs.cmu.edu/courses/fall2012/lectures/ICA.pdf) already answers a lot of questions, since it nice addresses the effects of statistical dependence and algorithmic realization.